# My bash_prompt cannot find a shell script

Tags: bash, prompt

This is a function I added to my .bash_prompt

```
function look_for_autorun() {
    echo "checking file"
    FILE="autorun.sh"
    if [ -x $FILE ]
    then
        echo "File '$FILE' Exists"
    else
        echo "The File '$FILE' Does Not Exist"
    fi
}
```

The file exists, but what I'm getting back says otherwise.  I can run the shell script manually, but I'd like to detect it when I go to that directory.

Comment: I'm guessing you changed directories.  Without a full path name, `[` will look in the current directory, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from `$ help test`, `-x FILE` is:

> True if the file is executable by you.

So you should make sure that `autorun.sh` is actually executable, e.g.:

```
chmod +x autorun.sh
```

Otherwise use `-e` to check just for existence.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  The script is executable by me.  Ran that command again just in case.  But I've used both -e and -x for test with the same result still applies.

Comment: This is strange, it works for me and it's fairly easy to reproduce: open a shell, evaluate your `function look_for_autorun() {...}`, `touch autorun.sh; chmod +x autorun.sh` and `look_for_autorun`. I get a positive reply.